# Check if richtextbox contains a string from a string array in vb

Tags: arrays, vb.net, string

```
Dim keywords() as string = {"word1", "word2", "word3"}
If Richtextbox1.text.contains(???,StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) Then
End if
```

I don't know to to write instead of "???".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check whether the RichTextBox contains any of those words as whole words (for example "This is word1" would match "word1" but "This is tword12" would not), you will need to decide how you want to divide the contents of the RichTextBox into words. The simplest way is to use String Split and split on spaces, but that might not do what you want if there is punctuation.

The following code uses that simple split and checks whether any of the words appear in the keywords array. The contents of the RichTextBox are converted to lower case to match the case of the keywords.

```
Dim keywords() as string = {"word1", "word2", "word3"}
Dim words() As String = RichTextBox1.Text.ToLower.Split({" "c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
If words.Count(Function(w) keywords.Contains(w)) > 0 Then
    'at least one word was found
End If
```

If you don't care whether the keywords appear as whole words, you can check like this:

```
Dim keywords() as string = {"word1", "word2", "word3"}
If keywords.Count(Function(w) RichTextBox1.Text.ToLower.Contains(w)) > 0 Then
    'at least one string from keywords was found
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use contains, you'll have to loop all of the keywords in your collection and check them one by one.

```
Dim keywords() as string = {"word1", "word2", "word3"}

For Each keyword In keywords
    If Richtextbox1.text.contains(keyword,StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) Then
    End if
End For
```